# Adding 15 to every figure to a column in R

Tags: r

I’m new to R and I’m trying to add 15 to every figure in my dataset for a specific column and was wondering how it’s possible to this. Any help would be much appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Asssuming you have a data.frame `df` with a column `col` that you want to increase:

```
df$col <- df$col + 15
```

No loop required, the fundamental objects in R are vectors.

Comment: Hi, appreciate the help but I couldn't get it to work.                                           
  tsunami_data
  colnames(tsunami_data)[1] <- "days_before"

Comment: Hi, appreciate the help but I couldn't get it to work.                                           
  tsunami_data
  colnames(tsunami_data)[1] <- "days_before"

Comment: tsunami_data$days_before <- tsunami_data$days_before + 15 should work.  Are you getting an error message?  Is tsunami_data a data.frame?