# How is it possible to add 15 to every figure in a column, in a tibble?

Tags: r

I am currently trying to add 15 to every figure in the column called days before. How is this possible? Any help would be much appreciated.

```
tsunami_data 
  colnames(tsunami_data)[1] <- "days_before"
```

Comment: It would be easier to help if you create a small reproducible example along with expected output. Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269). You had asked a similar question before https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69655132/adding-15-to-every-figure-to-a-column-in-r

Comment: `tsunami_data$days_before <- tsunami_data$days_before + 15`?

Comment: thanks for the help.